# How to encode video URLs in wordpress using base64?

Tags: php, wordpress, base64

```
<?php
$vid = get_post_meta($post->ID,'videourl', true);
$video = base64_encode($vid); 
$embedvideo =  get_post_meta($post->ID,'embedvideo', true);
$sefurL = get_bloginfo('template_url', true);
if($video != "") {  ?>
<?php if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) { 
echo'<object id="player" width="800" height="500" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">
    <param name="flashvars" value="file='.$video.' />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="src" value="'.$sefurL.'/inc/tools/jwplayer/player.swf" />
    <embed src="'.$sefurL.'/inc/tools/jwplayer/player.swf" autostart=false" wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="always" quality="high" FlashVars="file='.$video.'&width=800&height=500&skin='.$sefurL.'/inc/tools/jwplayer/blueratio.zip&repeat=false&autostart=false&image=big=true" quality="high" bgcolor="#000" width=800 height=500 name="jwplayer" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="https://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" allowfullscreen=true />
</embed>
</object>'; 
} else {
echo '<video src="'.$video.'" controls>
      Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
     </video>';
} 
?>
<?php } elseif($video == "" && $embedvideo != "") { ?>
<?php echo $embedvideo; ?>
<?php } else {
wpautop(the_content());
} ?>
```

As you see in the code I used `$video = base64_encode($vid);`  but when I do it in this way video not working more, so I don't have any experience with the base64 encoding I just searched on the Google but I couldn't find the right way to do it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `$vid` is a url, not the video file data, also why would you want to embed base64(which has a 33% overhead) video data into a webpage. Just use the url.

Comment: yes friend thankyou for your response, so without ` $video = base64_encode($vid);`  the video works fine in player ,exactly Im looking to find the right way to hide the url address, Im using mp4 files uploaded inm google drive than If I use the base 64 encoder for urls it will be better for me but when I use the codes like in the first post it encodes the url but video not playing :) this is all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be using base_64_decode(), it's likely the 'videourl' is already base64 encoded.  See how base64_encode() works in the 
[PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).

Try to echo the value of $vid to establish if it is already base64 encoded or not.

Comment: yes you are right thanks for the link Im looking nice examples

Comment: I used `<?php echo base64_encode($vid); ?>` intead the `'.$vid.'` but it didnt encode the url

Comment: Was there any output?  You might want to use `if(!empty($video))` instead of `if($video != "")`, as the value for `$video` may be null.

Comment: thanks but the video works also with if($video != "") but Im looking to decode the url of google drive using base64 encode I can get the video in player anyway Im gonna try your code but as I said video works fine I need only to hide google drive from url using any encode system, so with a better explantion the videourl in the line 1 is the custom field of the video url wich I want to encrypt